# AJAX Webform graphical bug?

Tags: ajax, webforms

I am using https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax for Drupal 7. I have a webform that is being submitted using ajax with the module above. heres what the form looks like:

[image: before]

however, if i submit the form without completing the required fields, the form itself seems to have some sort of graphics glitch (notice the black line at the bottom).

[image: after]

Comment: and what, if any, difference in html or css is there when you look at it in your browser's inspector tool?